# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x\mathop\to\infty}\frac{\tan x}{x}$

Tags: limits

I need to find $$\lim\limits_{x\mathop\to\infty}\frac{\tan x}{x}$$
For some reason mathematica just returns my input without evaluating it.

For what it's worth, $\dfrac{\tan(10^{100})}{10^{100}}\approx -4\times10^{-101}$, so the limit is probably $0$. (...)

I'm guessing this has been asked before but I can't find it.

Comment: Since $\tan x$ grows without bound at $\pi/2 + n\pi$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, it doesn't make much sense to evaluate it at the rather arbitrary value of $10^{100}$ and draw any conclusions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit does not exist: Since the tangent function has poles at every point of the form $\left(n + \frac 1 2\right) \pi$, the quantity

$$\frac{\tan x}{x}$$

is unbounded on every interval of length greater than $\pi$.

Comment: It's actually not even defined for $(n+\frac12)\pi$, so the limit doesn't really make sense.

Comment: What about the limit of the sequence $a_n=\tan(n)/n$?